# Regex 'Ignore Case' option doesn't work when the 'Compiled' option is specified

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following very simple regex, which matches  HTML tags in a string. I have the case insensitive option set, so that capitalisation of the tags doesn't matter. However, when the 'compiled' option is set, then the 'IgnoreCase' option seems to be ignored.

Sample code:

```
string text = "<SPAN>blah</SPAN><span>blah</span>";
Regex expr1 = new Regex("</*span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex expr2 = new Regex("</*span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Compiled);

MatchCollection result1 = expr1 .Matches(text); 
//gives 4 matches- <SPAN>,</SPAN>,<span> & </span>
MatchCollection result2 = expr2 .Matches(text);
//only gives 2 matches- <span> & </span>
```

Has anybody got an idea what is going on here?

Comment: Aside from the question, wouldn't "`</?span>`" be the better regex?

Comment: Yes, after thinking some more, </?span> is probably better.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are using a bitwise AND for your flags, you should be using a bitwise OR.

This bit:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Compiled
```

Should be:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled
```

[Here is a good article on how flags and enumerations work in respect to C#.](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx)

Comment: I make that mistake all the time. I'm writing my flags and out loud I'll say "I want option A **and** option B..."